# Concatenate URL and Text into Hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I need help to concatenate [SiteURL] with "_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx" and have the column be a clickable hyperlink.

From the [MS Column Formatting page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting), I need the href to be a column [SiteURL], not a static value.

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + @currentField"
   }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JSON:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "New App Registration",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "= @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx'"
   }
}
```

`@currentWeb` will evaluate to the absolute URL for the site.

---

**Update from comments**:

If you have a `SiteURL` in the same list which has site URLs, you can use JSON like below:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "New App Registration",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "=[$SiteURL] + '/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx'"
   }
}
```

Where `SiteURL` is the internal name of your column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: I think I mixed this up. The [SiteURL] is an entered column/field with a variety of SP site urls in each row. It's not a static url for the site I'm placing this formula into

Comment: You can replace the `@currentWeb` with `[$SiteURL]`. Where `SiteURL` is the **internal name** of your column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/

Comment: Awesome, yet again Ganesh!!  Thank you!